# How to Expose 2 graphql endpoints using netflix dgs library with spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, netflix-dgs

Is there a way to expose 2 graphql endpoints using spring boot netflix dgs library? As alternate, I have seen the post of using ServletRegistrationBean where we can define a GraphQLHttpServlet as a bean, and configure the context path to be /graphql, but this uses kickstart-library. Looking for similar pattern with using dgs-library with spring.